# Why are these magical methods not working?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

The result after running this code is below, can someone explain why isn't name passed properly so that it would say "Icefeet is years old"
Am I missing something here?

> is years old

```
<?php


class Penguin  {

  public function __construct($name) {
      $this->species = 'Penguin';
      $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function __toString() {
      return $this->name . " (" . $this->species . ")\n";
  }

  public function getPenguinFromDb($id) {
    // elegant and robust database code goes here
  }

  public function __get($field) {
    if($field == 'name') {
      return $this->username;
    }
  }

  public function __set($field, $value) {
    if($field == 'name') {
      $this->username = $value;
    }
  }

  public function __call($method, $args) {
      echo "unknown method " . $method;
      return false;
  }
}



$tux = new Penguin('Icyfeet');
echo $tux->created;
echo $tux->name . " is " . $tux->age . " years old\n";


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access username rather than name.

```
 public function __get($field) {
    if($field == 'name') {
      return $this->name;
    }
  }
```

Well, before that, please declare all the fields for the class like:

private $name = '';
private $species= 'Penguin';

Comment: I didn't want to define it as I was trying to get a grip on how method overloading with magic functions works, your advice about the username, however solved it (replace all 'username' to 'user'